# Canvas: Organizing shapes into arrays, and naming objects/shapes with variable

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas

I'm fairly new to `canvas`, and I have made a snake game from scratch. The snake is not restricted to vertical and horizontal, but can go many ways - that's why I have chosen to make the snake with circles.

Now my snake is infinite, which is not ideal. I would like to group the snake in an `array`, so I could use `array.shift` to remove the last circle/section of the snake, so the i could define a length on the snake.

Furthermore I would like to add some food to the `canvas`, and be able to remove it afterwards. But I can't figure out how to name shapes on the `canvas` with variables. I've searched all night, but I guess I am using the wrong wording or something... I know it's possible with KineticJS, but I would like to avoid KineticJS at this point.

So my questions are:

- How do I organize shapes into an array?
- How do I name a shape, with a Javascript variable?

Thank you so much. I suspect this to be newbie questions, but I can't find the answers anywhere...

Comment: Here's a post on creating the classic snake game: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/b5be7f/create-a-classic-snake-game-using-html5-canvas-in-10-simple/

Comment: That has nothing to do with my question, I'm afraid. I just need to know how to group shapes into `arrays` and how to name a shape with a `variable` name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I name a shape with a Javascript variable and organize a shape into an array?

You can define a multi-part shape as multiple javascript objects.

Then you can organize those multi-parts into an array which represents the total shape.

Something like this:

```
var snakeWidth=10;

var snake=[];

for(var i=0;i<10;i++){

    snake.push({
        x:i*snakeWidth,
        y:0,
        width:snakeWidth,
        height:10
    });
}

var foods=[];

for(var i=0;i<5;i++){

    foods.push({
        x:Math.random()*(canvas.width-10),
        y:Math.random()*(canvas.height-10),
        width:5,
        height:5,
    });

}
```

Then, for example, you can test all food objects in the foods[] array to see if the snake ate any particular food.

*About naming shapes with variables:*

You usually don't need to keep track of individual objects by naming them because you can just iterate through the array of all objects.  Instead you can name the array-container (snake,foods)

```
function eatFood(snakeX,snakeY){
    for(var i=0;i<foods.length;i++){
        var food=foods[i];
        if(snakeX>=food.x 
            && snakeX<=food.x+food.width 
            && snakeY>=food.y
            && snakeY<=food.y+food.height
        ){
            // The snake ate this particular food
        }
    }
}
```

**[ Addition: draw snake & food on canvas ]**

```
function draw(){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    ctx.fillStyle=snakeFill;
    for(var i=0;i<snake.length;i++){
        var s=snake[i];
        ctx.fillRect(s.x,s.y,s.width,s.height);
    }
    ctx.strokeStyle="black";
    s=snake[snake.length-1];
    ctx.strokeRect(s.x,s.y,s.width,s.height);

    ctx.fillStyle=foodFill;
    for(var i=0;i<foods.length;i++){
        var f=foods[i];
        ctx.fillRect(f.x,f.y,f.width,f.height);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. I get the idea, and this was what I was looking for BUT, how do I draw this `Array` to the `canvas`?

Comment: You're welcome!  I added code to my answer showing how to draw the snake[] and foods[] arrays on the canvas.  Good luck with you snakes game!